# BufferedReader reads a value which is somehow null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Ok, so I was doing a program which has a config file handler, and what it does is that it reads in the lines from a text file, which looks something like this:

```
ImagePath=SomePath
```

The method reads line by line matching the key with the corresponding line, and after that it then searches for the '=' character position in the String, and then substrings it such that the value `SomePath` is obtained. However, there is an issue.
Basically, the issue I am facing is that the reader is able to read the file, as I put a statement to print out the `lines` variable and it does print out the line read. However, the issue is that this `lines` variable would then be manipulated, but an NullPointerException error would occur around there (the `lines.substring(0,key.length()-1)` part), suggesting that the `lines` variable *suddenly* became `null` even though it is shown that something was read into the variable. Thing is, what happens to this variable in between the print statement and the string manipulation? I am unable to fix this issue. Pardon my code which might look messy or whatnot. I was trying multiple variations of my code to try to mitigate the issue, but it seems to not work. What is shown below is my latest variation of the code.

```
public static String readConfig(String key) throws IOException 
{
    BufferedReader reader=null; 
    try 
    { 
        reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(config)); 
    } 
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Failed to read file. Code: 3"); 
        System.exit(0); 
    } 
    String lines=reader.readLine(); 
    System.out.println(lines);
    String returnValue=null; 
    while(true) 
    { 
        if(key.equals(lines.substring(0,key.length()-1))) 
        { 
            int plusPos=0; 
            for(int i=0;i<lines.length();i++) 
            { 
                if(lines.charAt(i)=='=') 
                {
                    plusPos=i; 
                } 
            } 
            if(plusPos==0) 
            { 
                reader.close();
                return null; 
            } 
            returnValue=lines.substring(plusPos,lines.length()-1);
            reader.close();
            return returnValue; 
        } 
        lines=reader.readLine();
    } 
}
```

Edit 1: Ok, I see that Sbodd suggested that my code is kinda flawed, but well, the above snippet is just an instance to debug and test exactly which part of the loop does the line variable suddenly read null. Here is my original code snippet:

```
public static String readConfig(String key) throws IOException 
{
    BufferedReader reader=null; 
    try 
    { 
        reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(config)); 
    } 
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Failed to read file. Code: 3"); 
        System.exit(0); 
    } 
    String line; 
    String returnValue; 
    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) 
    { 
        line=line.trim(); 
        if(key.equals(line.substring(0,key.length()-1))) 
        { 
            int plusPos=0; 
            for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++) 
            { 
                if(line.charAt(i)=='=') 
                {
                    plusPos=i; 
                } 
            } 
            if(plusPos==0) 
            { 
                return null; 
            } 
            returnValue=line.substring(plusPos,line.length()-1); 
            return returnValue; 
        } 
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not the 'key' variable that is null

Comment: Yes I have checked. I've isolated everything to that. A few variations ago I had a `lines!=null` check, and the result was false. key works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string comparison will always fail.

```
if(key.equals(lines.substring(0,key.length()-1)))
```

Will attempt to match "ImagePat" and "ImagePath", which will fail. This will then cause a second iteration of the loop, with `lines` now equal to null.

Your comparison should be:

```
if (key.equals(lines.substring(0, key.length())))
```

Also, your return value should be

```
returnValue = lines.substring(plusPos + 1, lines.length());
```

to properly return the value.

You should also look at the `Properties` class, it will make things a lot easier.

Comment: Well, if I cannot fix this, I might take your advice and use the `Properties` class. Thanks!

Comment: @JosephLiuEngAnn You seem so surprised :)

Comment: I was more focused on the disappearing `line` value than the logic of the substring, which somehow made it work

Comment: `lines` disappears on the second readLine(), just before the loop iterates. `lines` will not be null the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will always throw a NPE when it reaches the end of the file.

From [the documentation for BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29):
[readLine returns] A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached.

Since your code is:

```
lines = reader.readLine();
while (true) {
  //do stuff with lines
  lines=reader.readLine();
}
```

when you reach end-of-file, `reader.readLine` will return null, you'll still pass your `while` check (since "true" is always true), and then you'll try and use that null pointer.

You could just replace `while(true)` with `while (lines != null)`.

A typical pattern to do this instead would be

```
while ((lines = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  //do stuff with lines
}
```

(Note that here, you don't make the first call to readLine outside the while loop, since your condition will be tested before the first execution of the loop.)

Comment: Actually, I had a previous variation which did that, but the thing is that `while ((lines = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  //do stuff with lines
}` would actually never execute because `while ((lines = reader.readLine()) != null)` would somehow be false. My code variation in the question was done in the hopes that it has something to do with the conditional operator and not the fact that the actual `lines` variable is null.

Comment: If you want, I'll do an edit with that variant. Maybe you can help me with that instead.

Comment: In that case, it's time to start gathering additional information.  What you have posted looks like it ought to work if you fix the while loop's termination.  Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger, and/or adding printouts at multiple places inside your loop?

Comment: yes I did, the problem pretty much starts as soon as it is compared with null